# Trouble creating a new array when old one is full

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently trying to implement my own version of a stack, which will be an array that contains structs. Here is the code:

```
struct some_struct{
    std::string name;
};

ExStack::ExStack(){
    cout << "Please enter a capacity for the stack: ";
    cin >> capacity;
    stack = new some_struct[capacity];
    size = 0;
}
    void ExStack::create_new_array(some_struct item){
        size ++;
        if (size == capacity){
        some_struct* new_stack = new some_struct[2 * capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            cout << stack[i];
            new_stack[i] = stack[i];

        }
        delete[] stack;
        stack = new_stack;
        capacity *= 2;
        delete[] new_stack;
    }
```

For debugging purposes, I'm currently entering `10` for the capacity of the ExStack, and then calling create_new_array until `size == capacity`. However, my code is crashing right when it gets to the for loop, as it tries to copy everything over to the new stack and delete the old stack. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the value of `capacity` when you enter that `if` statement?

Comment: Your code does not conform to any visible structure, making it hard to follow (global variables? ewww)... or just meaningless (for example `ExStack()` is never called). Anyway, your crash might be cause by your incorrect iteration of elements in `stack` in your `for` loop as you are exceeding the bounds of the array.

Comment: @sfletche If the user enters 10 when the `ExStack` is created, capacity would be 10. It can hold 10 items at most.

Comment: @Tyler - did you put a `cout` statement in there to test your assumption?

Comment: @sfletche Yes I did. Capacity stayed at 10.

Comment: How about `cout << stack[i];`...is that outputting anything?

Comment: This is terrible code, I find it hard to call this C++. I would *highly* recommend that you get a [decent book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and actually learn the language.

Comment: @sfletche That is actually giving me an error. Operand types are std::ostream << some_struct

Comment: @Tyler - The code is very hard to follow as to what you're doing.  You have a class called `ExStack` but you also have a stand-alone function called `create_new_array`.  Shouldn't that function be a member of your ExStack class?

Comment: @Tyler Please post your main() program that you're testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting the new stack that you created at the end of your function.

```
delete[] new_stack;
```

You only need `delete[] stack;` to get rid of the old memory.  The new memory that you allocated in `new_stack` needs to be kept.

Comment: But the program is crashing even during the for loop.

Comment: Then you really need to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  As is your `create_new_array()` function is missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: Sorry, I tried out your solution and it worked! Thank you very much!